# Domain name getting with number link: domain.com:399

Tags: php, .htaccess

While redirecting one page to another page using h t access getting attached extra number to domain
 e.g: "domain.com:399" here i need to remove ":399" form domain how to do this?

Comment: can you explain why is this attaching to domain...basically i don't have domain access so can we remove ":399" from htaccess while redirect.

Comment: please add your .htaccess file rules

Comment: basically we are redirecting one folder to another and we have added htaccess file in that folder like we have two folder "a" and "b" so redirecting a to b.
Here are the details:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Redirect /a/ /b/link.php?param=
</IfModule>
So here URL become like this:
domain.com:399/b/link.php?param=dummy

Comment: Thanks for help @bsy, i have solve the issue. below are the line those works for me:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /b/link.php?param=$1 [NC,QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this might work:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a 
RewriteRule (.*) http://[yourdomain]/b/link.php
```

Comment: i have just try but it's not working url not getting redirect is there anything those are missing. also last like i have tried both way like
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/b/link.php?param=  &  RewriteRule (.*) /b/link.php?param=

Comment: Thanks for help @bsy, i have solve the issue. below are the line those works for me: `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /b/link.php?param=$1 [NC,QSA,L]`